# Tekton task fails with `more than one PersistentVolumeClaim is bound`

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I'm trying to run a Tekton pipeline with a task that needs to access multiple `PersistentVolumeClaim` workspaces. When I run the pipeline, the task fails with the message `"more than one PersistentVolumeClaim is bound"`. As far as I can tell, there's nothing that forbids having more than one PersistentVolumeClaim bound in the same task, so why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to disable Tekton affinity assistant?

```
$ kubectl edit configmap feature-flags -n tekton-pipelines
```

Look for `disable-affinity-assistant`. Change its value to `true`.

See:

- https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/3480
- https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/3085

Also: make sure your Tekton stack is relatively up to date, as [there may have been some regression](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/2979) (unconfirmed) in 0.14.3.